# makefile with 2 executables, how?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

My project is organized like this :
src/plateau.c plateau.h tuile.c tuile.h main.c 
tests/tests.c
obj/
bin/

I'm trying to do a makefile with 2 executables. I can't figure out why it doesn't works.
The makefile with one executable only works fine, it looks like this :

```
CC = gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

DOXYGEN = doxygen

all: honshu

honshu: $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o            
    $(CC) $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o -o honshu

$(OBJDIR)/plateau.o: $(SRCDIR)/plateau.c $(SRCDIR)/plateau.h
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/plateau.c -o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o

$(OBJDIR)/tuile.o: $(SRCDIR)/tuile.c $(SRCDIR)/tuile.h
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/tuile.c -o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: $(SRCDIR)/main.c
    $(CC) -c -I src $(SRCDIR)/main.c $@ -lm

doxygen: 
    $(DOXYGEN) -g
    $(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm honshu
```

And with two executables, I tried like this :

```
CC = gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

DOXYGEN = doxygen

all: honshu tests

honshu: $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o
    $(CC) $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o -o honshu

tests: $(OBJDIR)/test_honshu.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o
    $(CC) $(OBJDIR)/test_honshu.o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o -o tests

$(OBJDIR)/plateau.o: $(SRCDIR)/plateau.c $(SRCDIR)/plateau.h
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/plateau.c -o $(OBJDIR)/plateau.o

$(OBJDIR)/tuile.o: $(SRCDIR)/tuile.c $(SRCDIR)/tuile.h
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/tuile.c -o $(OBJDIR)/tuile.o

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: $(SRCDIR)/main.c
    $(CC) -c -I src $(SRCDIR)/main.c $@ -lm

$(OBJDIR)/test_honshu.o: $(SRCDIR)/test_honshu.c
    $(CC) -c -I src $(SRCDIR)/test_honshu.c $@ -lm

doxygen: 
    $(DOXYGEN) -g
    $(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm honshu
```

But I have the following message "no rules to make "src/test_honshu.c", necessary for "obj.test_honshu.o", do you have an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Does the file `src/test_honshu.c` exist?  Try `make -d` or `make -p` to get some more information about what make is doing.

Comment: Thanks you're right, I didn't see that I moved my file... so this worked, but now it says that obj/test_honshu.o doesn't exists, it don't create it, but it has to make it when tests is called... or i'm wrong ?

Comment: You omitted the "-o". The comand should be `$(CC) -c -I src $(SRCDIR)/test_honshu.c -o $@ -lm`

Comment: @Beta's comment shows why you should use pattern rules etc. to avoid rewriting things over and over again.  Not only does it save your typing fingers but it avoids annoying typos.